# how to get a column value in radgrid on DeleteCommand event

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Hi All
I have a radgrid like this :

```
<cc1:RadGridCustomized ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGridCustomized1_NeedDataSource"
    OnPreRender="RadGridCustomized1_PreRender" OnUpdateCommand="RadGridCustomized1_UpdateCommand"
    OnDeleteCommand="RadGridCustomized1_DeleteCommand" OnInsertCommand="RadGridCustomized1_InsertCommand"
    OnItemCreated="RadGridCustomized1_OnItemCreated">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="گروه آزمایش" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("HSEWaterExamGroupName") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox OnDataBinding="RadGridCustomized1_ccbBinding3" runat="server"
                        ID="cbbHSEWaterExamsBaseGroup">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="نام ماده/ آزمایش" UniqueName="materialName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("HSEWaterExamBaseName") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox OnDataBinding="RadGridCustomized1_ccbBinding4" runat="server"
                        ID="cbbName">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtName" Enabled="false" Visible="false" runat="server" >
                  </telerik:RadTextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</cc1:RadGridCustomized>
```

now i want get the value of column "materialName" in DeleteCommand event. 
I use this code:

```
GridDataItem da = e.Item as GridDataItem;
string name = da["materialName"].Text;
```

or this code:

```
  name =  RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex]["materialName"].Text;
```

but the return value is string empty.
 plz help me if any one has idea to do this .
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First get the id and then from that id u will get name with:

```
int id = (int)e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["ID"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UniqueName to get the value of the column:

`da.item["UniqueName"].Text`